# Is it possible to overwrite database records from dump?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a dump of PostgreSQL database, which I created with command:

```
pg_dump database_name > dumpname.sql
```

I would like to restore database from this dump but I get manny errors "...already exists". Is it possible to overwrite existing database records from dump? I have to restore database, but I can't drop it.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the `--clean` option of `pg_dump`, the tables will be dropped and recreated.

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but ended up here after getting into the same issue. Giving you downvote because it was asked "can't drop it", while `--clean` causes a drop to the table

Comment: OP said he cannot drop the database, but put no such restrictions on the tables.